# Basic registration form, logic is wrong

Tags: php, registration

I am trying to create a basic registration script. When leave all the forms blank, I get a a message saying that I have not used a valid email address, but I would like it to tell me that I have not inputted any data, and do this if any form is left blank. Logic does not seem to be correct, its probably a minor problem, but I cannot find it.

homepage.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    require 'functions.php';

    registration_form();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
function registration_form() {

echo '<form id="register" action="register.php" method="post">';
echo '<fieldset>';

echo '<legend>Register</legend>';

echo '<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="1" /></br>';

echo '<label for="email">Email Address:</label></br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="100" /> </br>';

echo '<label for="password">Password:</label></br>';
echo '<input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="60" /></br>';

echo '<label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label></br>';
echo '<input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" maxlength="60" /></br>';

echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">';

echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
}

function validate_registration($password, $confirmpassword, $email) {

    if ((!isset($email)) || (!isset($password)) || (!isset($confirmpassword))) {


    registration_form();
    echo "Please enter the required information:";

    }


    elseif ((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && ($password == $confirmpassword)) {

        echo "You have registered with: $email";

    }

    elseif ((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && ($password !== $confirmpassword)) {

        registration_form();

        echo "Your password does not match!";
    }

    else {

        registration_form();
        echo "You have not entered a valid email address!";
    }
}
```

register.php

```
require 'functions.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

validate_registration($password, $confirmpassword, $email);
```

Comment: Not really PHP related, but if you know Javascript, then you can use JQuery to check if the form fields empty, and only submit if the form is complete.

Comment: Client-side validation is great to reduce round-trips to the server, but don't blindly trust anything coming from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use

```
if (!empty([VARIABLE]))
```

in your validation check, as those parameter values are going to be set as zero-length strings when you POST.  Thus they will will not work with `!isset` because the values ARE set and ARE NOT `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/it/function.empty.php) function rather than `isset()`

```
if ((empty($email)) || (empty($password)) || (empty($confirmpassword))) {
```

This happens because also if field are not filled with any values, `isset()` is still set as empty, you could check that if you dump you post array `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: You mean `if ((empty($email))`, rather than `if ((!empty($email))`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out php [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

> Just a note, because I didn't know for sure until I tested it.
>
> If you have a query string that contains a parameter but no value (not
>   even an equals sign), like so: `http://path/to/script.php?a`

```
 The following script is a good test to determine how a is valued:
<pre> <?php  print_r($_GET);  if($_GET["a"] === "") echo "a is an
 empty string\n";  if($_GET["a"] === false) echo "a is false\n"; 
 if($_GET["a"] === null) echo "a is null\n";  if(isset($_GET["a"]))
 echo "a is set\n";  if(!empty($_GET["a"])) echo "a is not empty"; ?>
 </pre>
```

> I tested this with script.php?a, and it returned:
>
> a is an empty string a is set
>
> So note that a parameter with no value associated with, even without
>   an equals sign, is considered to be an empty string (""), isset()
>   returns true for it, and it is considered empty, but not false or
>   null. Seems obvious after the first test, but I just had to make sure.
>
> Of course, if I do not include it in my browser query, the script
>   returns Array ( ) a is null

Answer (score 0):

This is form submit hence each variable is set, but in your case, with empty values. Try `empty()` instead of `!isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

What about `if(variable)`?

In the past I've used it to determine if the variable was present and had a value which would return true. If not, it would return false.

I would also check for lengths of the vars. In case both `password` and `confirmpassword` are empty strings, so they would both be equal.